# How to use a for loop in a procedure

Tags: for-loop, vhdl, procedure

I need to use a for loop in a procedure to affect all the bits of a signal, otherwise the code would be enormous.

My code looks like this:

```
FSM : process(CLK, RST)
    procedure Reset is
    begin
        triplet_check_vec <= (others=>'0');
    end Reset;

    procedure triplet_check is
    begin
        for k in 0 to 19 loop
            triplet_check_vec(k) <= (DATA_IN(3*k+0) and DATA_IN(3*k+1) and DATA_IN(3*k+2)) or (not(DATA_IN(3*k+0)) and not(DATA_IN(3*k+1)) and not(DATA_IN(3*k+2)));
        end loop;
    end triplet_check;

begin
    if RST = '1' then
        Reset;

    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
        -- some stuff
        -- ...

        triplet_check;

        -- ...
        -- some stuff
    end if;

end process FSM;
```

For some reason, `triplet_check_vec` is initialized by the procedure `Reset`, but not affected by the procedure `triplet_check`.

Any idea why?

Comment: How is `triplet_check_vec` declared? What is `CLK`? Does it have a rising edge? What is `some stuff`? What is `DATA_IN`?

Comment: You are right I didn't give enough details.

CLK is an std_logic, it does have rising edges.

triplet_check_vec is an std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)
DATA_IN is an std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)

What I first did is affecttriplet_check_vec bit by bit in the procedure triplet_check, and it worked. The only difference now is the loop, and it doesn't work anymore

Comment: So e.g. for `k = 19`, you are accessing `DATA_IN(3*k+2)` which is `DATA(57+2)` which is `DATA(59)` which doesn't exist. There is something wrong with how you calculate these indexes.

Comment: is "triplet_check_vec" not redefined inside the scope of the procedure? Can you try making the procedure with in and output parameters defined?

Comment: sorry I said a mistake, DATA_IN is std_logic_vector(59 downto 0)

Comment: Why does it need to be a procedure? you can use a loop inside a process in the same way.

Comment: @Tricky, because it is often used in the code so it is lighter in a procedure

Comment: Does `RST` ever go to `'0'` or something other than `'1'`?

Comment: @user_007 just once at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

A procedure’s parameter list defines its inputs and outputs, kind of like a mini-module. It can be a signal or a constant, but unlike a module, it can also be a variable. For more details [How to use a Procedure in VHDL](https://vhdlwhiz.com/using-procedure/)

The basic syntax for creating a procedure is

```
procedure <procedure_name> (signal|variable|constant <name1> : in|out|inout <type>;
                            signal|variable|constant <name2> : in|out|inout <type>;
                            ... ) is
    <signal_constant_or_variable_declarations_for_use_within_the_procedure>
begin
    <code_performed_by_the_procedure_here>
end procedure;
```

For your example

```
procedure triplet_check (constant DATA_IN             : in    std_logic_vector(59 downto 0);
                         variable triplet_check_vec   : out   std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)) is
begin
    for k in 0 to 19 loop
        triplet_check_vec(k) <= (DATA_IN(3*k+0) and DATA_IN(3*k+1) and DATA_IN(3*k+2)) or (not(DATA_IN(3*k+0)) and not(DATA_IN(3*k+1)) and not(DATA_IN(3*k+2)));
    end loop;
end triplet_check;
```